# Gridview how to Subtract two item

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view.In this i want balance= total paid leave-paid leave taken
what shoul i do

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Paid Leaves" SortExpression="Location_name">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txttotal_paid_leaves" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("total_paid_leaves") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewtotal_paid_leaves" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("total_paid_leaves") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Paid Leaves taken">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtpaid_leaves_taken" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("paid_leaves_taken") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewpaid_leaves_taken" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
    </FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblpaid_leaves_taken" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("paid_leaves_taken") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Balance">
    <ItemTemplate>

    ----Please guide me in this part----

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like this

```
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%#Convert.ToInt32(Eval("TotalLeave")) -Convert.ToInt32(Eval("LeaveTaken")) %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do that calculation in sql? That's better and easy to manage.

for eample

```
SELECT TOTAL_LEAVE, LEAVE_TAKEN, (TOTAL_LEAVE - LEAVE_TAKEN) BALANCE
FROM TABLE
WHERE .......
```

Comment: Ok, where is total paid leave column in your gridivew? Which column - Which column exactly? You have to write your code in RowDataBound event. Provide me to get balance Which Column - Which Column in your gridview?

Comment: I just want to show Balance part show subtraction of Total leave -leave taken in jast after leave taken column

Comment: @Piushshukla mark it as accepted. so that other will  get benefit from it. click on Right mark and accept the answers

Comment: @Piushshukla y u are not calculating it from SQL and return it as a column. I think that approach may render your control faster and avoid datarowbound call.If you have a 1000 rows, 1000 times it will calls for this subtraction. So my suggestion is to perform this in SQL as Mr Lwin Oo Said.